# How to create multiple sessions

Tags: php, jquery

I want help on my application where the user can create multiple sessions. You can acess the application [here](https://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/create_session2.php). Please follow the steps below to be able to use the application:

1. Open the application
2. Please enter in "3" in the number of sessions textbox and "1" in the number of questions textbox and then click on the "Prepare Questions" button.
3. A confirmation box should appear, click "OK".

This will direct you into a new page known as "QandATable2.php" and this is where the user gets to create questions and answers for each session. At the bottom it states the number of sessions and questions you have chosen from the last page. Now please follow the steps below to use this page:

1: There are 4 controls at the top of the application, "Questions", "Options and Answers", "Replies" and "Number of Marks". Please do this below:

- Type in a question in the "Question" textarea
- In the "Options and Answers" control, click on the "Open Grid" and select "3", buttons A - C would appear. Then in the "Number of Answers" textbox enter in the number "1". Select one button from either A, B or C (button turns green when selected).
  -In the "Replies" control select "Single" radio button.
- In the "Number of Marks" section type in "0".

When you have done all this then click on the "Add Question" button.

1. You will now see that the question you have created is added into a new table row.
2. Now click on the "Submit Details" button below.
3. A confirmation box would appear, click "OK".
4. The session is created and the page is navigated to the "session_marks2.php" page (It displays an error page because I have not created this page yet".

Now what the problem is that we have stated that we wanted "3" sessions to be created, we have only created one session.

What I want to happen in this example is that after the user has created the first session, when the user clicks "Ok" in the confirmation box, then what I want is that I want the first session details to be stored in a temporary database (I do not want it to be stored in the proper database because lets say user has created a session but doesn't complete the other sessions, then it will mess the full database up with incomplete data) and then it should navigate the user to the same page (QandATable2.php) so the user can create the questions and answers again for the second session (which is 1 question as already mentioned)  and then after second session created, save second session details in the temp database and then create third session. After third session completed then save it into temp database.

The reason I want a temp database is because lets say the user wants the same question from session 1 into session 2, then I want something where the user clicks on a button and they are able to select a previous question so when this happens the details of that question is stored in the top control and then the user can click on the "Add Question" button to add the question in a new row.

I know I am asking a lot but this is a huge thing in the application and what would be very helpful is if somebody can compile a simple demo showing how this can be achieved. I will be very greatful if this can be achieved. I am using php and Jquery coding.

Thank you and comment to me if there are any issues. Thank you :)

Comment: Why actually do you need multiple sessions?

Comment: Because lets say you teach three classes and you wnat them to take an exam but you do not want the classes to take exaclty the same exam, then you can create multiple exams (sessions) so that you can change questions between the exams so students a taking different exams. Class 1 could take exam 1 (session 1), Class 2 could take exam 2 (session 2) and class 3 could take exam 3 (session 3). This means that a class who has already taken an exam cannot give exact answers to people who are taking their exam later on as they will be taking a different exam. Does that make sense?

Comment: nope. What you have asked has nothing to do with sessions. At least with term `session` used in web development

Comment: I am not using session in web development term. I meant the word session as in an exam period. Multiple sessions means multiple exams. If I want 3 sessions that means I want to create 3 exams.

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is a difference between your use of the word `session` and the technical implementation of a `session` on the server.

If you want 3 or 4 different 'sessions' for your user, you can easily do that by storing 3 or 4 different variables (arrays for example) in the `$_SESSION` variable.